# Is it possible to wrap a middle div only into the next row using css

Tags: html, css

Consider the following code

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">LEFT</div>
        <div class="center">CENTER</div>
        <div class="right">RIGHT</div>
    </div>
```

Is it possible to wrap the center div to the next row when the viewport becomes smaller? After which we will have the left and the right divs on the upper row and the center div on the lower row?

Is it possible with css alone? Or does one require javascript/typescript?

A code example would be nice. Thank you.

Comment: you could use flex with a media query to change the order  for when you want the center on the lower row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can actually be done without Flex and without Grid (which results in superior backwards compatibility).

```css
.col {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: .5em;
}

.container .left {
 float: left;
 background: #fc3;
 min-height: 20em;
 width: 50%;
}
.container .right {
 display: inline-block;
 background: #3cf;
 min-height: 20em;
 width: 50%;
}
.container .center {
 float: left;
 clear: left;
 width: 100%;
 background: #3fc;
 min-height: 20em;
 min-width: 20em;
 
}
@media all and (min-width:60em) {
 .container .left,
 .container .right {
  width: 25%;
 }
 .container .center {
  clear: none;
  width: 50%;
 }
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left col">LEFT</div>
        <div class="center col">CENTER</div>
        <div class="right col">RIGHT</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why are you floating the center div left? then clearing it... i know the code won't work without it but I don't understand how it works...

Comment: That's how the trick works. The left and center columns float left, leaving space next to the left column above the center column. Actually using the clear property isn't necessary, since the center column will automatically drop below the left column when its width is large enough for it not to have room to sit next to the left column. I should mention the **major limitation**: when the right column is taller than the left column, it will drop below the center column. There is a workaround, but it requires knowing the height of the taller of the left and right columns.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `flex` or `grid` container, then there is property `order`, that you could use.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.left{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;

}
.right{

  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}
.center{

  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 599px){

  .container{
    width: 480px;
  }
  .center{
    order: 3;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="left">LEFT</div>
 <div class="center">CENTER</div>
 <div class="right">RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/jv0n8mg9/1/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use flex and on the container and change the `order` of the `center` div.

See code below, and wrap it in a `@media only screen(max-width: 768px)` or what breakpoint you need.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container div {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.center {
  order: 3;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
        <div class="left">LEFT</div>
        <div class="center">CENTER</div>
        <div class="right">RIGHT</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With CSS grid it would look like the following:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.container > div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.left {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

.center {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
}

.right {
  grid-column-start: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="left">LEFT</div>
        <div class="center">CENTER</div>
        <div class="right">RIGHT</div>
    </div>
```